# Braiins OS won't build

Tags: linux, hardware

## Problem

there's no way to build [Braiins OS](https://github.com/braiins/braiins) from the source. we tried bb.py, the docker guideline, and building `bosminer` with cargo, and calling the lede make file on branches `firmware_latest` and `bos_release`. with each of the methods we ended up in errors. the errors and exceptions we've got are as follows.

### 1. Running docker builder

the guideline we went through is [the official website](https://docs.braiins.com/os/open-source-en/Development/2_build.html#building-latest-firmware-images-in-docker)

#### Commands executed

1. `cd braiins/braiins-os`
2. `./docker/build-docker-container.sh`
3. `./docker/build-in-docker.sh zynq-am1-s9`

#### Errors and exceptions

```
INFO:root:Preparing LEDE build system...
-- prepare:default_config
.  prepare:config
scripts/config/conf: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by scripts/config/conf)
/src/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/include/toplevel.mk:114: recipe for target 'defconfig' failed
make: *** [defconfig] Error 1
TaskError - taskid:prepare:config
PythonAction Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/build/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/doit/action.py", line 424, in execute
    returned_value = self.py_callable(*self.args, **kwargs)
  File "/src/braiins-os/builder/dodo.py", line 50, in <lambda>
    task.update({'actions': [lambda: next(generator, None)]})
  File "/src/braiins-os/builder/builder.py", line 1020, in prepare_config_doit
    self._run('make', 'defconfig')
  File "/src/braiins-os/builder/builder.py", line 565, in _run
    process = subprocess.run(args, input=input, stdout=stdout, check=True, cwd=cwd, env=env, preexec_fn=init)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('make', 'defconfig')' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

```
INFO:root:Preparing LEDE build system..
.  prepare:config
scripts/config/conf: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by scripts/config/conf)
/src/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/include/toplevel.mk:114: recipe for target 'defconfig' failed
make: *** [defconfig] Error 1
TaskError - taskid:prepare:config
PythonAction Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/build/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/doit/action.py", line 424, in execute
    returned_value = self.py_callable(*self.args, **kwargs)
  File "/src/braiins-os/builder/dodo.py", line 50, in <lambda>
    task.update({'actions': [lambda: next(generator, None)]})
  File "/src/braiins-os/builder/builder.py", line 1020, in prepare_config_doit
    self._run('make', 'defconfig')
  File "/src/braiins-os/builder/builder.py", line 565, in _run
    process = subprocess.run(args, input=input, stdout=stdout, check=True, cwd=cwd, env=env, preexec_fn=init)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('make', 'defconfig')' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

```
INFO:root:Start cleaning LEDE build directory...'
scripts/config/mconf: error while loading shared libraries: libncursesw.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/src/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/include/toplevel.mk:127: recipe for target 'menuconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [menuconfig] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/src/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede'
/src/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/include/toplevel.mk:94: recipe for target '.config' failed
make: *** [.config] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bb.py", line 370, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./bb.py", line 364, in main
    args.func()
  File "./bb.py", line 119, in clean
    builder.clean(purge=self._args.purge)
  File "/src/braiins-os/builder/builder.py", line 1109, in clean
    self._run('make', 'clean')
  File "/src/braiins-os/builder/builder.py", line 565, in _run
    process = subprocess.run(args, input=input, stdout=stdout, check=True, cwd=cwd, env=env, preexec_fn=init)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('make', 'clean')' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

to simplify the log I have removed the successful steps. please let me know if you need them.

#### Steps taken

1. installed `lib32z1` and `libncurses5`

### 2. Running bb.py

we learned from the source that to debug we can add the log flag. and it revealed bb.py is calling a problematic make file located in `zynq/lede`

#### Commands executed

1. `python3.5 bb.py --log debug build`

#### Errors and exceptions

```
DEBUG:root:Run 'make defconfig' in '/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
-- prepare:public_key
-- prepare:secret_key
INFO:root:Start building LEDE...'
DEBUG:root:Run 'make -j4' in '/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede'
 make[1] world
 make[2] tools/install
 make[2] package/cleanup
 make[3] -C tools/flock compile
 make[3] -C tools/flock install
 make[3] -C tools/sed compile
 make[3] -C tools/sed install
 make[3] -C tools/xz compile
 make[3] -C tools/patch compile
 make[3] -C tools/tar compile
 make[3] -C tools/xz install
 make[3] -C tools/patch install
 make[3] -C tools/tar install
 make[3] -C tools/m4 compile
 make[3] -C tools/expat compile
 make[3] -C tools/pkg-config compile
 make[3] -C tools/sstrip compile
 make[3] -C tools/make-ext4fs compile
 make[3] -C tools/patch-image compile
 make[3] -C tools/scons compile
 make[3] -C tools/mtools compile
 make[3] -C tools/lzma compile
 make[3] -C tools/squashfs4 compile
 make[3] -C tools/pkg-config install
 make[3] -C tools/expat install
 make[3] -C tools/sstrip install
 make[3] -C tools/make-ext4fs install
make -r world: build failed. Please re-run make with -j1 V=s to see what's going on
make: *** [/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/include/toplevel.mk:200: world] Error 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bb.py", line 370, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "bb.py", line 364, in main
    args.func()
  File "bb.py", line 139, in build
    builder.build(targets=self._args.target)
  File "/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/builder/builder.py", line 1159, in build
    self._run(args, path=path, init=partial(os.umask, 0o0022))
  File "/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/builder/builder.py", line 565, in _run
    process = subprocess.run(args, input=input, stdout=stdout, check=True, cwd=cwd, env=env, preexec_fn=init)
  File "/home/max/.anaconda3/envs/bos/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', '-j4']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

### 3. Calling lede make file manually

from `bb.py` with `--log debug` it got transparent that a make file located in `braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede` is broken. so we executed that manually to see the logs.

#### Commands executed

1. `cd braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede`
2. `make -j1 V=s`

#### Errors and exceptions

```
freadahead.c: In function 'freadahead':
freadahead.c:91:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
   91 |  #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
      |   ^~~~~
make[7]: *** [Makefile:1837: freadahead.o] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/build_dir/host/m4-1.4.17/lib'
make[6]: *** [Makefile:1602: all] Error 2
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/build_dir/host/m4-1.4.17/lib'
make[5]: *** [Makefile:1506: all-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/build_dir/host/m4-1.4.17'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1461: all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/build_dir/host/m4-1.4.17'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:29: /home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/build_dir/host/m4-1.4.17/.built] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/tools/m4'
make[2]: *** [tools/Makefile:148: tools/m4/compile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede'
make[1]: *** [tools/Makefile:145: /home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9+neon_musl-1.1.16_eabi/stamp/.tools_install_yynyyyyynyyyyynyynnyyyynyyyyyyyyyyyyyyynyynynnyyynnny] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede'
make: *** [/home/max/rust/braiins/braiins-os/build/zynq/lede/include/toplevel.mk:200: world] Error 2
```

#### Steps taken

1. installed `m4` to resolve `freadahead.c` but it didn't work

### 4. Building Rust with cargo

the Rust codes builds on a local machine that does not set a target with no problem. but when it comes to target `arm-unknown-linux-musleabi`, everything breaks.

#### Commands executed

1. downloaded `arm-linux-musleabihf-cross` from [musl.cc](https://musl.cc/)
2. `CC=/home/max/Downloads/arm-linux-musleabihf-cross/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc cargo build --release --target arm-unknown-linux-musleabi`

#### Errors and exceptions

```
error: linker `arm-openwrt-linux-muslgnueabi-gcc` not found
  |
  = note: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: could not compile `bosminer-erupter` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

### Platform

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

cargo: cargo 1.60.0 (d1fd9fe 2022-03-01)

rustup: rustup 1.24.3 (ce5817a94 2021-05-31)

python: Python 3.5.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.

I am eagerly looking for advice for resolving this matter.
thank you very much.

Comment: `GLIBC_2.27 not found` but required by defconfig.

Comment: Hi @Navid, Is this issue fixed?

Comment: yes, we continued testing. in the end, we lowered the version of Ubuntu in docker until we got the result. @Rex

Comment: @Navid Awesome! If you don't mind can share the details of Ubuntu version you test that works on your end? Thanks in advanced!